# Bootstrap Collpase toggle (or not collapse) does not work

Tags: razor, .net-core, bootstrap-4

Below is my first attempt to build a Razor page w/ Boostrap.  When the page is first brought up, the form is collapsed.  When the user clicks on the Revisit a quote button, the form then expand.  I followed the documentation on Bootstrap's site to the dot, but no idea getting the toggle to work.  What am I missing?

```
@page "/"

<div>
<label>What would you like to do?</label>
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button">
  Create a new quote
</button>
</div>
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#quotesearchForm"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="quotesearchForm">
  Revisit a quote
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="quotesearchForm">
  <form>
  <input /><div class="dropdown" /><button></button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved...out of the box Blazor only has the bare-bones structure from Bootstrap and does not have the javascript portion.  What Blazor wants you to do is to use its **code** to eliminate the use of javascript.  Blazor does that by using its SignalR technology to transmit very small amount of data over the wire to do that.  Tim Corey has a YouTube video on this.